# How do I pass a function as a parameter with it's own parameters in c++

Tags: c++

Trying to call a function that gets used as an argument for another function, while passing it's own arguments. Example in pseudoish c++ code:

```
void function1(argument(x)) ///I believe this should be void function1(void(*argument)(int)), but i try to call it as *argument(); and that fails also
{
    doStuff;
    argument(x);
    doMoreStuff;
}

void function2(int x)
{
     int test;
     test = x + 2;
     doOtherStuffWithx;
}

int main()
{
    int test = 1;
    sample = function1(function2(test));
}
```

haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might consider a [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/10077).

Comment: std::bind allows you to bind the function pointer to the argument so that it can still be called later.  That way you only have to pass a single parameter to function1: https://onlinegdb.com/Tf6M6auHG

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: I think that would make a good answer.

Comment: `function1` declaration is not valid or "well-formed" C or C++. May be it was 25 years ago with _implicit-int_ and _optional-return-type_ rules, but not nowadays. You should fix that error first or use a compiler from that era.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: I think fixing that error would be the answer the OP is looking for, hence why it is referred to as "pseudoish c++ code".

Comment: @FredLarson Oh, I see now, said a blind man. Voting to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `std::bind` was needed before C++11. In C++11 and on `std::bind` is worse in space and time than C++11 lambda captures, and, therefore, `std::bind` shouldn't ever be used. `std::bind` is essentailly C++03 poor man's C++11 lambda capture.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Fair enough.  And that's why it was a comment instead of an answer.  However, I don't think std::bind existed before C++11 - before that everyone used Boost.Bind, didn't they?  According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind std::vind is since C++11. 
 Anyway, I don't know what version of C++ the OP can use - perhaps that version doesn't have lambdas.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `boost::bind` wanted to be a part of C++ standard before C++03. It only got included in C++11, but native lambdas got there at the same time making `std::bind` unnecessary. But it wasn't clear if any of `std::bind` or native lambdas would get into C++11 at all.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `boost` is the origin of these libraries that later got into `std`. By the time `boost` libraries get into `std`, the latter is merely an old and incomplete version of current `boost`, so I never switched to `std` knock-offs. `boost` also fixes mistakes even if that breaks the ABI, whereas `std` versions bit-rot unmodified until they become barely usable and deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest for you would be to program it like that:

```
#include <functional>

void function1(std::function<void(int)> func, int arg)
{
    //doStuff;
    func(arg);
    //doMoreStuff;
}

void function2(int x)
{
     int test;
     test = x + 2;
     //doOtherStuffWithx;
}

int main()
{
    int test = 1;
    function1(function2, test);
}
```

If you want to use some function with arbitrary number of arguments and types, then you can use templates:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void function1(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    //doStuff;
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    //doMoreStuff;
}
```

Comment: so std::function acts as a wrapper in this case? Would a reference be the same?

Comment: `function1` function template would avoid conversion to `std::function`, which may involve memory allocations. There is a tradeoff between zero overhead and having to expose `function1` implementation and non-zero overhead of `std::function` and not having to expose `function1` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use [a lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) calling the function with the desired parameter, and pass that as a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) that your `function1()` accepts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void function1(std::function<void()> f)
{
    std::cout << "Stuff before...\n";
    f();
    std::cout << "... stuff after.\n";
}

void function2(int x)
{
     int test;
     test = x + 2;
     std::cout << test << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    int test = 1;
    function1([=]() { function2(test); });
}
```

Comment: The example is sub-optimal as demonstrated because conversion to `std::function<void()>` is not zero cost, but there is no clear benefit of paying that cost.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Feel free to edit.

Comment: I just share my thoughts. Your answer is your repsonsibility, but thank you for the invite.